# Use source_group from a subdirectory in cmake

Tags: cmake

In cmake you can can group source files in your IDE with the `source_group` command (in my case it creates filters in the Visual Studio project).

I have a directory structure like this

```
Main (dir)
  +-- CMakeLists.txt
  +-- main.cpp
  +-- shaders(dir)
        +-- CMakeLists.txt
        +-- shader1.glsl
        +-- shader2.glsl
```

Main/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.13)
add_executable(myExec main.cpp)
add_subdirectory(shaders)
```

shaders/CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_sources(myExec PRIVATE shader1.glsl shader2.glsl)
```

If I add `source_group("Config Files" REGULAR_EXPRESSION ".*\.glsl")` to Main/CMakeLists.txt it creates a filter that contains shader1.glsl and shader2.glsl as expected. If I however use it in shaders/CMakeList.txt it doesn't add a filter and the shader1.glsl and shader2.glsl appear directly in the myExec project.

To me it looks like `source_group` only applies to targets that are created in the same CMakeList.txt file. This behaviour isn't obvious to me from [its documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/source_group.html).

Is this documented anywhere? And is there any way to use `source_group` from a subdirectory (would be the most logical thing to me to keep everything shader related in shaders/CMakeLists.txt)?

Comment: The documentation has been updated meanwhile:

"The group is scoped in the directory where the command is called, and applies to sources in targets created in that directory."
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.23/command/source_group.html